# how to handle log in through Facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a webapp with PHP as backend, and I wanted the user to be able to login through a few social media(fb, linkedin, insta).
I had gone through Facebook's login API and am still confused.

Here are the bit I needed through the login:
1. Bio Details
2. User's link to social media

To get these information I will need to ask for permission and I can get both of the information I needed.

But here is what I don't understand

Questions:
1. Other than the 2 information needed, what else should I store in the database? (Accesstoken?)
2. How can we authenticate the user? through which information returned from the API?(Accesstoken, id or ?)